# Umbrello wont create relation

Tags: uml, umbrello

I am trying to add an aggregation relation from 'Property' -> 'ConsumerPropertySelected' object, but it wont add any type of relation. (See the image)

If I invert the direction ('ConsumerPropertySelection' -> Property) then it adds a relation but the aggregation diamond is pointing in the wrong direction

(Currenlty I pick the relation from the toolbar and drag it between 2 objects, which worked for all the other relations... Not sure if there is a different way to do it or some setting I am missing)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug, however there is a workaround.

1. Select the relation you want from the toolbar.
2. Left Click and hold on the first object(ex: 'Property')
3. Whilst still holding the left mouse button, drag the cursor to the second object (ex: 'ConsumerPropertySelected')
4. Release your left mouse button over the second object
5. and finally click the second object again with your left mouse button

If it doesn't work the first time, try it again and it should create it... Hopefully this bug will get fixed soon

EDIT:
Looks like the bug is fixed: https://cgit.kde.org/umbrello.git/commit/?id=42d5073216f6801fef68dd6a4508b9a0e1f67ef1
The fix will probably be deployed with the next release

Comment: I have reported the bug @ https://umbrello.kde.org/developers.php: BugID 409161 - Umbrello wont create a UML diagram relation between two objects